# Android layout-normal folder is not working

Tags: android

please help me. I put this xml file in layout-normal folder but it doesn't work as figure-2. Why the layout-normal is not working here? this is how xml file look like figure-1.

[when I have been created layout-normal folder for multiple screen support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1RZS.png)

[why the layout-normal is not working..this is how xml file look like figure-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiBPQ.png)

[but it does not work as figure-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebDME.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".basketBall_0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basketBallCurrentMatchesNumberTextViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/loading"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basketBallCurrentClubNameTextViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/loading"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/basketBallCurrentMatchesNumberTextViewId" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout8"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:background="@drawable/broader1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/basketBallPlayerORTeamTwoNameEditTextId"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/team_name_two"
            android:textColor="#050505"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.687"
            android:autofillHints=""></EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/basketBallPlayerORTeamOneNameEditTextId"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:hint="@string/team_name_one"
            android:textColor="#050505"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="text"></EditText>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/broader1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/basketBallGameStartNowButtonId"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/basketBallRoundTimeSetId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/set_your_time_as_minutes"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            android:autofillHints="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/for_round_time"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basketBallGameStartNowButtonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiantimo"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/game_start_now"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```